# Can't use JavaScript to change innerHTML to "\f"

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, mathjax

I'm honestly stumped. I was working on a program and I narrowed down the problem to an incredible degree; whenever I try to change the innerHTML of an element to "\f" it doesn't display.

Note: I've only tried this on CodePen and JSFiddle; 2 online code editors. I'm not sure if my problem is the websites, or JavaScript. I'd prefer to keep this online as it's the best choice for portability.

Also Note: Just in case anyone was wondering, I need this to use the MathJax Library for JavaScript. (\Frac specifically)
https://codepen.io/FoodLover195/pen/mBzoyG

HTML:

```
<p id="Test">Hello World</p>
<p id="Test2">Hello World</p>
<p id="Test3">Hello World</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = "\f";
document.getElementById("Test2").innerHTML = "\food";
document.getElementById("Test3").innerHTML = "\fried \food";
```

Comment: (Code blocks need a blank line above them)

Comment: If you really want to show `\f` then add another slash `.innerHTML = "\\f";`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to put `\f` in the text?  If so, use `\\f` to avoid escaping the f.

Comment: Even simpler: open your browser console and type `'\f'`… → `""`

Comment: ...there has to be a dupetarget for this...

Comment: Thanks for the real quick replies... like that was insanely fast.

Answer (score 2):

`\f` is an escape sequence for a formfeed (U+000C) in a string literal in JavaScript (and most other languages with C-like syntax). To put an actual backslash in a string literal, use `\\` (e.g., `\\f`).

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an [escape character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation). You need to escape the `\` character. In other words:

```
document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = "\\f";
document.getElementById("Test2").innerHTML = "\\food";
document.getElementById("Test3").innerHTML = "\\fried \\food";
```